# Как отсортировать результат выборки ::find из двух разных моделей по полям с разным названием

Tags: php, массивы, yii2, сортировка

Создаю массив внутри которого 2 элемента. Эти элементы в свою очередь тоже массивы, в них находится результат выборки `::find` из двух разных моделей. Проблема в сортировке полученных данных по ключам.

Вот код который делает выборку и объединяет ее:

```
    $mergedArray = array_merge(
    //выборка из таблицы thisDay
            ThisDay::find()
            ->where(
                    new Expression(
                    "day = :dateDay"
                    . " AND id_region = :id_region"
                    . " AND month = :month", [":dateDay" => $dateDay,
                ":month" => $currentMoth,
                ":id_region" => REGION_ID]))
//                        ->orderBy("news_date DESC")
            ->all(),
    //поиск по таблице News с лимитом 4 - (минус) кол-во новостей в ThisDay
    News::find()
            ->alias("n")
            ->select()
            ->where(
                    //выборка по дню
                    new Expression("EXTRACT(DAY FROM cdate) = :userDay "
//                                                выборка по региону,
                    . "AND id_region = :id_region "
//                                                выборка по месяцу,
                    . "AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM cdate) = :userMonth "
//                                                выборка по году,
                    . "AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM cdate) "
//                                                выборка по статусу,
                    . "AND status > :stat AND n.id NOT IN"
                    //и чтобы id не совпадало с id из таблицы this_day
                    . " (SELECT id_news FROM this_day)",
                    //агрументы для бандинга
                    [":userDay" => $dateDay,
                ":userMonth" => $currentMoth,
                ":id_region" => REGION_ID,
                ":stat" => 1]))
            //новости с самым высоким рейтингом
            ->joinWith("rating nr")
            ->orderBy("nr.rate DESC")
            ->limit(4 - ThisDay::find()
                    ->where(
                            new Expression(
                            "day = :dateDay"
                            . " AND id_region = :id_region", [":dateDay" => $dateDay,
                        ":id_region" => REGION_ID]))
                    ->count())
            //группировка и сортировка по дате
            ->orderBy("cdate_int DESC")
            ->groupBy("EXTRACT(YEAR FROM cdate)")
            ->all());
```

На выходе ( `var_dump($mergedArray));`) структура такая:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  object(***\***\***\***\ThisDay)#244 (8) {(тут пошел массив для нулевого элемента массива и первого для ThisDay за 2017 год)}
  [1]=>
  object(***\***\***\***\ThisDay)#244 (8) {(тут пошел массив для первого элемента массива и второго для ThisDay за 2016 год)}
  [2]=>
  object(***\***\***\***\News)#244 (8) {(тут пошел массив для второго элемента массива и первый для News за 2017 год)}
  [3]=>
  object(***\***\***\***\News)#244 (8) {(тут пошел массив для третьего элемента массива и второй для News за 2016 год)}
```

**Важно:** в зависимости от результатов выборки какой то из массивом может быть пустым вовсе и это будет работать корректно. Массив каждый отдельно друг от друга сортируется в нужном порядке от большего к меньшему, т.е друг без друга они выглядят корректно. Но как только массивов два и года элементов выборки НЕ идут в идеальном порядке, например, `"2017 2016 2015 2014"`, а содержат, например, такой порядок: `"2017 2016 2016 2017"` то сортируются они отдельно друг от друга, вот так: `"2017 2016 2017 2016"`.

Я пытаюсь решить эту проблему переиндексацией массивов отдельно друг от друга:

```
            //индексирую, если ThisDay
        $indexedThisDay = ArrayHelper::index($mergedArray, function ($element) {
                    if ($element instanceof ThisDay) {
                        return (int) \Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($element['news_date'], 'yyyy');
//                        return $element['news_date'];
                    }
                });
        //индексирую, если News
        $indexedNews = ArrayHelper::index($mergedArray, function ($element) {
                    if ($element instanceof News) {
                        return (int) \Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($element['cdate_int'], 'yyyy');
//                        return $element['cdate_int'];
                    }
                });
```

`['news_date']` и `['cdate_int']` хранят данные в едином формате timeStamp но из за легаси названия полей отличаются. Теперь тут в каждой переменной по массиву, структура у них (`var_export($indexedThisDay);`) примерно следующая:

```
array (
  2017 => 
  ****\****\****\****\ThisDay::__set_state(array((тут пошел элемент массива для 2017 года ThisDay и т.д))
  2016 => 
  ****\****\****\****\ThisDay::__set_state(array((тут пошел элемент массива для 2017 года ThisDay и т.д))

(var_export($indexedNews);) 
  2017 => 
  ****\****\***\***\News::__set_state(array((тут пошел элемент массива для 2017 года ThisDay и т.д))
  2016 => 
  ***\***\***\***\News::__set_state(array((тут пошел элемент массива для 2017 года ThisDay и т.д))
```

Отлично, теперь отдельно друг от друга я могу их сортировать по ключу (году). Но мне то нужно в представление отправить все 4 элемента. Поэтому я делаю следующее:

```
$model = array_merge($indexedThisDay, $indexedNews);
```

Т.е я мержу два массива с целью объединить их в один и сортировать уже его, но
вот что выдает `var_dump($model);`

```
array(4) {
      [0]=>
      object(***\***\***\***\ThisDay)#244 (8) {(тут пошел массив для нулевого элемента массива и первого для ThisDay за 2017 год)}
```

И так все 4 элемента.

Т.е я опять возвращаюсь к тому, что у меня неверно отсортированный массив из 4 значений, ключи потерялись.

Вопрос: как я могу отсортировать свой результат выборки так, словно это один единый массив как грамотно объединить их для сортировки? Буду рад критике и советам как решить проблему с сортировкой по ключу или по значениям полей `['news_date']` и `['cdate_int']`

UPD: я пытался сортировать вот так:

```
    $arrOut = array();
    foreach ($result as $subArr) {
        // разберем подмассив на ключи и значения
        foreach ($subArr as $key => $val) {
            // если значение с таким ключом существует, и оно больше текущего, то ничего не делаем
            if (isset($arrOut[$key]) && $arrOut[$key] > $val)
                continue;
            // добавляем значение во внешний массив
            $arrOut[$key] = $val;
        }
    }
```

и вот так:

```
function sortBy($array) {
    usort($array, function ($item1, $item2) {
        if ($item1 instanceof News) {
            if ($item1['cdate_int']) {
                $newsArr = $item1['cdate_int'];
            }
        }
        if ($item2 instanceof ThisDay) {
            if ($item2['news_date']) {
                $thisDayArr = $item2['news_date'];
            }
        }
        if ($thisDayArr == $newsArr)
            return 0;
        return ($thisDayArr < $newsArr) ? -1 : 1;
    });
    return true;
}

$this->sortBy($model);
```

Но это не дало никаких результатов, массивы по прежнему сортируются отдельно друг от друга.

Comment: Доброе утро. В yii2 есть yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(). Сначала получите данные из базы и только после этого подставляйте значение в ArrayHelper::merge();, зачем выполнят сложный запрос в методе? Так же есть yii\db\ActiveRecord::toArray(), при помощи этого метода можно получить в результат массив, а не объект.

Comment: @slo_nik Добрый вечер. Пробовал делать ровно так как вы говорите, т.е разбить выборки по переменным и мержить уже их, результат тот же, к сожалению)

Comment: @slo_nik по поводу объекта в массив - объект позволяет мне использовать в представлении функции, которые прописаны в модели, массив меня этой функциональности лишает.. я имею ввиду что то такое `$value->getImgUrl()`

Comment: Значит проблема у Вас изначально в запросах. Если Вам не помог ArrayHelper::merge(), то это не значит, что Вы сможете решить вопрос при помощи array_merge()

Comment: Для однообразия можно написать геттер, возвращающий timestamp в моделях и использовать это значение как ключ, а потом отсортировать массив по эначению поля

Comment: @slo_nik прямо сейчас сделал все следуя Вашему совету) создал две переменные, в одну поместил выборку для thisDay, в другую для News. Смержил их через ::merge. Модели не смешались и отсортировались отдельно друг от друга, т.е результат тот же

Comment: @ilyaplot можете пожалуйста подробнее рассказать про геттер? Как это можно было бы реализовать?)

Comment: В двух моделях пишем `public function getTimestamp() {return $this->news_date; }` Во второй возвращаем cdate_int. Получаем "поле", которое есть в обеих моделях вот так: `$item->timestamp;`