# Как избежать Integrity constraint violation при выполнении связанного запрос в yii

Tags: php, yii2, activerecord

Необходимо выполнить запрос из двух таблиц, например, News и ThisDay. Общих данных в них нет, мне просто необходимо получить данные из обоих этих таблиц так, будто это одна выборка. Пытался выполнить путем смерживания двух выборок, но в таком случае выборки из разных таблиц не смешиваются, подробнее [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/812483/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8-find-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BC-%D1%81-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7). При чем из ThisDay будут выбираться все новости за указный день и месяц, а из News будут выбирать так, как указано в условии limit(). Вот сам код выборки:

```
$newsFromTwoTables = ThisDay::find()
        ->where(
                new Expression(
                "day = :dateDay"
                . " AND id_region = :id_region"
                . " AND month = :month", [":dateDay" => $dateDay,
            ":month" => $currentMoth,
            ":id_region" => REGION_ID]))
        ->orderBy("news_date DESC")
        ->joinWith('news')
        ->where(
                new Expression("EXTRACT(DAY FROM cdate) = :userDay "
                . "AND id_region = :id_region "
                . "AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM cdate) = :userMonth "
                . "AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM cdate) "
                . "AND status > :stat AND n.id NOT IN"
                . " (SELECT id_news FROM this_day)", [":userDay" => $dateDay,
            ":userMonth" => $currentMoth,
            ":id_region" => REGION_ID,
            ":stat" => 1]))
        //новости с самым высоким рейтингом
        ->with("rating nr")
        ->orderBy("nr.rate DESC")
        ->limit(4 - ThisDay::find()
                ->where(
                        new Expression(
                        "day = :dateDay"
                        . " AND id_region = :id_region", [":dateDay" => $dateDay,
                    ":id_region" => REGION_ID]))
                ->count())
        ->orderBy("cdate_int DESC")
        ->groupBy("EXTRACT(YEAR FROM cdate)")
        ->all();
```

После этого я передаю переменную $newsFromTwoTables в представление, как модель.
При попытке открыть представление получаю ошибку, представленную на рисунке ниже.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно исправить запрос на выборку так, чтобы избежать этой ошибки?

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день.

Вам необходимо назначить псевдоним для таблиц и использовать его с названиями столбцов.

```
$newsFromTwoTables = ThisDay::find()->from(['date1' => ThisDay::tableName()])
    ->where(
            new Expression(
            "date1.day = :dateDay"
            . " AND date1.id_region = :id_region"
            . " AND date1.month = :month", [":dateDay" => $dateDay,
        ":month" => $currentMoth,
        ":id_region" => REGION_ID]))
    ->orderBy("date1.news_date DESC")
    ->joinWith('news')
```

Второй псевдоним пусть будет date2

```
->limit(4 - ThisDay::find()->from(['date2' => ThisDay::tableName()])
            ->where(
                    new Expression(
                    "date2.day = :dateDay"
                    . " AND date2.id_region = :id_region", [":dateDay" => $dateDay,
                ":id_region" => REGION_ID]))
            ->count())
```

Указать псевдонимы во всём запросе.

Comment: _Указать псевдонимы во всём запросе._ - Вы же это уже за меня сделали, верно? Просто я использовал который Вы предоставили и ошибка сохранилась та же

Comment: Использовали ->orderBy("date1.cdate_int DESC") , да?

Comment: понимаете ли, тут такое дело, что я пытаюсь как бы просто выбрать данные из двух таблиц.. так вот эта конструкция она относится не к таблице this_day а к news, т.е к связанной таблице.. т.е по идее ей не нужен алиас)

Comment: я просто не знаю (я стажер) как выбрать данные из двух таблиц в yii так, чтобы они потом сортировались в хронологическом порядке. Мне посоветовали сделать union и поэтому я решил сделать что то типа union но с применением join'a) Если бы вы могли, было бы очень круто, если бы вы показали как выбирать данные из двух таблиц так, будто это одна выборка...

Comment: Ну если бы не нужен был, то не было бы ошибки.) У Вас ругается на cdate. Значит нужен псевдоним.

Comment: Для этого надо созвониться в skype и видеть Ваш живой сайт.